# Destructing struct

Tags: c, struct

In my program I'm using constructions like:

```
typedef struct R{
    float s1;
    float s2;
    float s3;
}Rtype;
```

and then:

```
typedef struct Z{
    Rtype rval[8][8];
}Ztype;
```

What am I trying to do next is to recover 3 2-dimensional tables of floats and use them separately. To do that I use:

```
Ztype* b;
float f[8][8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      if(mask == 0)
        f[i][j] = b->rval[i][j].s1;
      else if(mask ==1)
        f[i][j] = b->rval[i][j].s2;
      else
        f[i][j] = b->rval[i][j].s3;
```

But I think that there should be a way to do it better. So my question is: how can I do that?

Comment: @Kevin: 1. I ate *. 2. this is only an example of what I'm doing.

Comment: I hope in your actual code `b` is initialized.

Comment: @Medinoc: of course it is ;)

Comment: Are the dimensions of three tables dependent? This could effect your design choices...

Comment: @awashburn: it's always gonna be 8x8, for all three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, here are the first that crossed my mind:

1. Inspect the `mask` *once*, and pick a different loop that just does the right thing, assuming `mask` never changes in the loop.
2. Inspect `mask` once and compute a pointer offset from the base of each `rval`, and use that to copy the float. The assignment would become something like `f[i][j] = *(float *) ((char *) b.rval[i][j] + offset);` which looks scary but should compile into something decent.
3. Use a `union` to overlay an array with the `s1`, `s2` and `s3` fields, so you can do `f[i][j] = b.rval[i][j].u.array[mask];` or something like that.
4. Inspect `mask` once and set a function pointer to the proper assignment function. This might be expensive if function calls are expensive, though.

I'd probably go with the first or second.

Answer (score 0):

Use macro replacement or a pointer to one-D array like this:

```
Rtype (* pRval)[8] = b->rval;

// ...

f[i][j] = pRval[i][j].si;
```

Seems a little better :).